# how to replace keycode by another in vaadin framework?

Tags: user-interface, vaadin

I need to set the ENTER key to navigate between enabled fields placed on a com.vaadin.ui.Panel.  How can i programmatically do this?

This is my intent but doesn't now how to send a keypress:

```
Action ENTER_KEY_ACTION = new ShortcutAction(
         "Enter key"
        , ShortcutAction.KeyCode.ENTER
        , null
        );

public Action[] getActions(Object target, Object sender) {
    return new Action[] { ENTER_KEY_ACTION};
}

public void handleAction(Action action, Object sender, Object target) {
    if (action == ENTER_KEY_ACTION ) {
        ENTERKeyHandler();
    }
}

protected void ENTERKeyHandler(){
   //
   //here i need to send a TAB keyPress
   //
}
```

this code work perfectly up to now but isn't ended. I don't know if there is another way to accomplish this?
please sorry my English too.

Answer (score 0):

The AbstractComponent class provides a method for this (Your field object extends AbstractComponent). The method is called *fireEvent(Component.Event event)*.

You could try to send an event to the registered listeners with this approach.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm trying to do this at Panel instance level and in other hand, fireEvent is declared as protected method. I think this way I'll need to subclass AbstractComponent and this is too much complicated looking into the future development for all class of focused components. I'm trying to use just vaadin components and some addons but not my own components yet. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a [FocusListener](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/event/FieldEvents.FocusListener.html) to your fields in the Panel, which keeps track of the currently focused field. You also have to know the tabbing order of the fields on the server-side and in the ENTERKeyHandler() method you call field.focus() for the field to be focused.

Comment: Thanks Henri. I'll try this way creating some class of traversal focus policy and handlers for this, keeping must simple way, at first need to search a little for this kind of already implemented things. I do not want to reinvent the wheel.